# Creating an async method in .NET 4.0 that can be used with "await" in .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, .net-4.5

I have a .NET project that uses C# in .NET 4.0 and VS2010.

What I would like to do is add some async overloads to my library to make doing async programming easier for users in .NET 4.5 with the await keyword. Right now the methods that are being overloaded are non-asynchronous. Also I don't want to use any async methods myself, just create new ones and make them available.

Is creating async methods in .NET 4.0 and VS2010 possible and if so, what should the .NET 4.0 async method look like?

Because I'm using VS2010 I don't have access to the "async" keyword so what needs to happen to emulate that behavior in .NET 4.0? For example does it need to return any particular type, and does any code need to happen inside the method to make the currently non-asynchronous code it is calling happen asynchronously?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As others have stated, you start by having a method return `Task` or `Task<TResult>`. This is sufficient to `await` its result in .NET 4.5.

To have your method fit in as well as possible with future asynchronous code, follow the guidelines in the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern document](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=19957) (also available [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx)). It provides naming conventions and parameter recommendations, e.g., for supporting cancellation.

For the implementation of your method, you have a few choices:

- If you have existing `IAsyncResult`-based asynchronous methods, use [`Task.Factory.FromAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync.aspx).
- If you have another asynchronous system, use [`TaskCompletionSource<TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174.aspx).

Comment: Also, I would add the obvious possibility of using `async/await` when compiling with VS 2012 or later, either by using the framework implementation, the [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.bcl.async) package implementation, or (for experts only) rolling your own.

Comment: @JeanHominal: While an `async` method is definitely the easiest possibility, it is outside the scope of this question, since the op is limited to VS2010.

Comment: The answer provided is for .NET 4.5 when the user asked for .NET 4.0.

Comment: @hc1: No, the answer is describing methods available in 4.0 (returning `Task`/`Task<TResult>` and `Task.Factory.FromAsync` or `TaskCompletionSource<TResult>`).

Answer (score 9):

The simplest way to do this is to return a `Task` or a `Task<T>`. That will be enough.

However this only makes sense if your method really executes asynchronously.

I also recommend that you follow the usual pattern of naming them like AbcAsync ("Async" suffix). Your callers will not notice any difference to an async method created with C# 5 (because there is none).

Tip: Just adding async to the method does nothing. Your method will execute sequentially and return a completed task. Making the method return a task must serve a certain purpose - usually this is done because the method inherently executes asynchronously (like a web-service call or file IO).

If your method only contains computation but no IO (or only blocking IO) it is usually better not to make it async because you gain nothing doing that. Async methods do not always execute on a separate thread. If that last sentence surprised you, you may want to dig a little into this topic.

Comment: The method that I want to overload (with the Async suffix added) isn't asynchronous. The .NET 4.5 examples I have read appear to make a method automatically asynchronous by adding the "async" keyword. I want to know how to replicate this in .NET 4.0. I've updated my question so this is a little clearer.

Comment: I edited my response into the answer. If all you want is to spawn the methods code on a different thread, use Task.Factory.StartNew in your caller. You wouldn't need to change the method for that.

Comment: @JamesNewton-King: An async method always returns `void` or `Task` or `Task<T>`. From the *caller's* point of view, how it returns a `Task` or `Task<T>` is largely irrelevant. I think it would be worth you reading up a bit more about what async methods *really* do.

Comment: "If your method only contains computation but no IO (or only blocking IO) it is usually better not to make it async because you gain nothing doing that." <- can you explain more on that?

Comment: @Chin what would you gain by doing that? Leave it to the caller to initiate parallelism or move the computation off of the UI thread. Threading is not the business of that computation method.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you return a Task that completes somehow (whether in a thread or asynchronously), you would support the async model..

Having a Task execute asynchronously is another story. If you had access to the async keyword and the API you could simply base your method on async calls to other, already supplied async methods. But in this case, you have to hand-craft your async Tasks.

There might be better ways to do it, but the most elegant way I can see (and have used) is to utilize `System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource` to construct a task, use `Begin`/`End` model of asynchronous methods to execute whatever you need to execute. Then, when you have the result on hand, post it to the previously constructed `Task` instance using your completion source.

It will certainly be asynchronous, just not as fancy as the ones in upcoming release.

**Disclaimer:** I'm no way near an expert on this. Just made some experiments on.