# We need to have "double" await so that GUI will not freeze?

Tags: c#, user-interface, responsive-design, task-parallel-library, async-await

I expect my GUI will not hang, after reading [Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)

```
    public async Task<string> DoBusyJob()
    {
        // Busy Job
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        i++;
        return "Finished " + i;
    }

    int i = 0;

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Hang!
        string result = await DoBusyJob();

        this.label1.Text = result;
    }
```

**But, it is not. It still hang.** I realize I need to add additional `await` in `DoBusyJob`

```
    public async Task<string> DoBusyJob()
    {
        // Busy Job
        await Thread.Sleep(10000);
        i++;
        return "Finished " + i;
    }

    int i = 0;

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // OK!
        string result = await DoBusyJob();

        this.label1.Text = result;
    }
```

May I know why is it so? Do I really need to have **double** `await`? What if the following case?

```
    public async Task<string> DoBusyJob()
    {
        // How to prevent Hang?
        for (int j = 0; j < 10000000; j++) {
            double m = Math.Sqrt(1) + Math.Sqrt(2) + Math.Sqrt(3);
        }
        i++;
        return "Finished " + i;
    }

    int i = 0;

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Hang!
        string result = await DoBusyJob();

        this.label1.Text = result;
    }
```

Comment: The async keyword doesn't magically make your for loop code run on a background thread. What you want to do is `await Task.Run( () => DoExpensiveCpuCalculations());`

Answer (score 6):

Please see [the excellent answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9574845/185200) in regards to `async` methods.

Adding `async` is insufficient to make the execution of your method asynchronous if you are not using `await` with already asynchronous methods.  In that case, you need to return a `Task` instance that represents the execution of your work, for ex. by calling `Task.Factory.StartNew`.

Answer (score 2):

There's a great answer in the [`async` / `await` FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/12/10293335.aspx):

> Q. Does using the “async” keyword on a method force all invocations of that method to be asynchronous?
>
> A. No. When you invoke a method marked as “async”, it begins running synchronously on the current thread...
>
> Q. Does the “async” keyword cause the invocation of a method to queue to the ThreadPool? To create a new thread? To launch a rocket ship to Mars?
>
> A. No. No. And no...

You may find my [`async` / `await` intro](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could understand your `// OK!` upon adding  `await` to  `Thread.Sleep(10000);`
It is impossible to await on method `Sleep()` returning `void`
It is possible to await only on method designating its signature `Task` or `Task<TResult>` as return type

Async method is executed synchronously without (or until) `await` so blocking UI thread
await Task.Run() should return at once to (previous) UI synchronization context, i.e. to continue with next i++; line execution

```
public async Task<string> DoBusyJob()
{
  // Busy Job

  await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10000000; j++)
        {
            double m = Math.Sqrt(1) + Math.Sqrt(2) + Math.Sqrt(3);
        }
    }
                );
  i++;
  return "Finished " + i;
}
```