# C# .net 4.5 code to .net 4.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

in visual studio 2012 .NET 4.5 i have this

```
 public async void Execute(object parameter)
    {
      task = action(parameter);
      OnCanExecuteChanged();
      await _task;
      OnCanExecuteChanged();
    }
```

can i have the same exact behavior in .NET 4.0 Visual studio 2010 without async and await and without hanging the UI?

Comment: Did you see this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574790/creating-an-async-method-in-net-4-0-that-can-be-used-with-await-in-net-4-5?rq=1

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/10/22/using-async-await-without-net-framework-4-5.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use this code:

```
//To invoke the OnCanExecuteChanged in same thread that the Execute method
var scheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
_task.ContinueWith(t => OnCanExecuteChanged(), scheduler);
```